# Finding maximum value in range containing same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, array-formulas

I have data:

```
A       B
1       100
1       300
1       200
2       100
2       500
3       100
3       300
3       200
```

I want to select maximumof(B) for same value in column1. Output should be:

```
A       B       C
1       100     300
1       300     300
1       200     300
2       100     500
2       500     500
3       100     300
3       300     300
3       200     300
```

I have tried:

```
={Max(if(A:A=A1,B:B))}
```

This gives me the maximum value for `1` i.e. `300`.

How can I copy this formula for other group of cells? It gives message *You Can not move array values*.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497411/excel-maxif-function-or-emulation

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `{=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))}`? It's working fine on my spreadsheet and I'm on Excel-2007

Comment: @mr.Reband: solution mentioned in the link is same as what I have tried. It works for that cell. I will be having thousands of rows. How can implement same for all the rows?

Comment: @Jerry this works for me as well. suppose I want to check max where A.value=2 my formula will be {=MAX(IF(A:A=A4,B:B))} (P.S. a4 because 2 starts at 4rth row). It will work fine for me. But i dont want to copy paste this formula if i have 100 different values in A. Please let me know if I am not being clear

Comment: What happens if you double-click the little black box (on lower right corner of selected cell containing formula) to drag down the formula?

Comment: My output is 300
300
200
500
500
300
300
200
which is wrong.. it should be 300 300 300 500 500 300 300 300

Comment: There's something wrong then. I took your sample values and it gives me your desired output. If you can open an xlsx file, here's my output [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Example.xlsx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you delete ColumnC and start again - using your formula in C1. Then either drag C1 down as far as required or copy it and past it into C2:C whatever. But make sure the `=` is inside the curly brace.

Comment: It is an array formula. and if i drag it down, it gives me an error "You can not change part of an array". I mentioned this error in comment on john's answer

Comment: Thanks, It worked..I was doing something silly while copy pasting it. Thank you everyone for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this - The one I came up with used array formulas.
Type this in:

```
=MAX((--(A:A=A1))*(B:B))
```

And then hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` to make it an array formula

Hope this does the trick

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply. Problem here is I want to use this formula only once. Suppose, I add 100 rows of data, then by simply copying the formula to 100th row will give me the output shown in question.

Comment: This does that... Just copy the formula down... Otherwise, I don't understand what you're saying.... I tried it on your inputs and got exactly the outputs you showed....

Comment: If I copy the formula down, it gives me error "You can not change part of an array".

Comment: When pasting the array formula, don't include the cell which you copied. For example, copy cell `C1` and paste to `C2` onwards... **DO NOT INCLUDE `C1` IN THE PASTE**...