# Finding a max value in a column based on a previous column in Excel

Tags: excel, max, lookup

I have an Excel work sheet that holds a list of cures carried out. I would like to create a table on another worksheet withthin the same workbook that will show users what the latest number of a given component is that has been cured. The data is logged like so (other columns not relevant are not shown). I would like a formula that looks down Column B for a part (FIS), then look down Column C and find the highest value in all rows that have FIS in Column B.

Column A / Column B / Column C

Cure Number / Component / Spar No.

49-2013-05-W2R-1    /  FIS  / 10030

36-2013-06-W2R-2    /  FOP  / 10030

46-2013-16-W2R-1    /  FOS  / 10030

32-2013-05-W2R-2    /  RIP  / 10030

I'm sure this is simple but not conversant on some of formulas like Vlookup, match, index etc.

47-2013-23-W2R  /  RIS /    10030

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497411/excel-maxif-function-or-emulation) please try:

```
=MAX(IF(B1:B100="FIS",C1:C100,))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or adjust the range limits to suit.